# ActionMailer + Sidekiq/Redis Sending Duplicate Emails Repeatedly - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, actionmailer, sidekiq

I'm running rails and redis in development environment on a local ubuntu 18 machine.

The ActionMailer is sending emails appropriately, however it seems as if my computer is off and I come the next day to fire up redis, it resends a bunch of emails.

```
#invoice controller
InvoiceMailer.send_invoice_to_email(email, @invoice).deliver_later

#InvoiceMailer
    def send_invoice_to_email(email, invoice)
        @invoice = invoice
        attachments["test_invoice_#{invoice.id}_#{Date.today}.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
            render_to_string(pdf: 'Invoice', template: '/invoices/show.pdf.erb', layout: 'application')
        )

        bcc = ["test <test@test.com>", "test2 <test2@test.com>"]
        mail(from: "Test <info@test.com>", to: email, bcc: bcc, subject: "Invoice From test")
    end
```

What could my problem be and how would I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - I believe that there were NOT duplicate emails being sent out. I had some issues with the logic. If this is happening to you, first ensure that sidekiq is not queuing emails that are then sent out later on at the same time. Also, it gets confusing if you are testing this by sending actual emails - be careful of how you add "to", "cc", "bcc".